# .NET Remoting with Service that uses DAAB with Unity giving null reference exception

Tags: .net, remoting

I have a project that is using Unity and I am trying to implement NET Remoting.  I have a NET Remoting Server for an existing Service Layer that has a Data Layer using the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block. The problem is that due to Remoting requiring a parameterless constructor when the TestService is called I am
getting a null reference exception. Any ideas on how to implement this with Unity?

Here is my code:

TestService from Service Layer:

```
public class TestService : MarshalByRefObject, ITestService
{
    private ITestRepository repository;

    public TestService(ITestRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;        
    }

    public TestService() <--- parameterless constructor
    {}

    public List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        return repository.GetBooks();
    }
```

TestRepository from Data Layer:

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    private Database db;

    public TestRepository(Database db)
    {
        this.db = db;      
    }

    public List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
      List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
        list.Add(new Book(1, "test book 1"));
        list.Add(new Book(2, "test book 2"));
        return list;
    }
```

Book class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Book : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Book() { }
    public Book(int id, string name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Simple test RemotingServer:

```
TestRepository testRepository;
TestService testService;

IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
container.AddNewExtension<DataAccessBlockExtension>();


container.RegisterType<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();

container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

testService = container.Resolve<TestService>();

TcpServerChannel channel = new TcpServerChannel(9988);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(TestService), "TestService", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
System.Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key");
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Simple Remoting Client:

```
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new TcpClientChannel());
ITestService testService = (ITestService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ITestService), "tcp://localhost:9988/TestService");

foreach(Book item in testService.GetBooks())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Book:\n" + item.Name);    
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Here is the full exception:

```
line 40 is calling repository.GetBooks();
at Test.Services.IssueService.GetBooks() in TestService.cs:line 40
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
```

Comment: _Where_ did you get the exception? Please post the whole thing: ex.ToString(). When did this start happening? Is this new code? And, why aren't you using WCF for this; it has replaced Remoting.

Comment: Added the full exception. This is new code just written.

Comment: The client application for this application is cross platform(Linux,Mac, Windows) through Mono. I had thought of using WCF, but I don't believe from my initial research that there is WCF implementation that is complete in Mono. Initially I was going to use WCF and this would be a non issue.